# CORS React + php

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, fetch, cors

Мне нужно отправить Post запрос на локальный сервер, но получаю эту ошибку:
`Access to fetch at 'http://test/reg.php' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`
Много гуглил, но ничего не помогает. Что мне сделать, чтобы это заработало?

Comment: в домене, к которому делаешь запрос надо дать разрешение на доступ http-заголовками https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: спасибо, конечно, но вопрос заключается в том, как это сделать

Comment: там три сценария работы, твой первый

Comment: Это может помочь. https://stackoverflow.com/q/8719276/2873538